# Automatic Update in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

We have three Silverlight applications that run out of browser. We have code in these applications so the application will automatically be updated when a new version becomes available. This feature has suddenly stopped working in one of the three applications. The code as far as I can tell is the same in all three applications. 
If I uninstall and reinstall the application by running it from a browser and right-clicking to uninstall and reinstall that works ok. But this is not a great solution because it means I have to visit each user to fix their desktop.
I trace this a bit and found I was reached the paragraph that checks for update but e.UpdateAvailable is false. I’m not sure what to try next.

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup



    Me.RootVisual = New MainPage

    Dim l_CurrentHost As String = App.Current.Host.Source.OriginalString

    If l_CurrentHost.Contains("localhost") = True Then

        Exit Sub
    End If


    If App.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser Then


        m_Update.startProgress()

        m_Update.Show()

        AddHandler App.Current.CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted, AddressOf DownloadUpdateCompleted
        App.Current.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync()


    End If



End Sub
Private Sub DownloadUpdateCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompletedEventArgs)
    m_Update.endProgress()
    'Exit Sub
    '   MessageBox.Show("1")

    '   MessageBox.Show("We got to #3 " & e.UpdateAvailable)

    If e.UpdateAvailable Then

        MessageBox.Show("An application update has been downloaded, and will close. " & _
        "Restart the application to run the new updated version.")

        App.Current.MainWindow.Close()

    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
        TypeOf e.Error Is PlatformNotSupportedException Then

        MessageBox.Show("An application update is available, " & _
            "but it requires a new version of Silverlight. " & _
            "Visit the application home page to upgrade.")
    Else
        '  MessageBox.Show("2")
        ' MessageBox.Show("There is no update available.")
    End If

End Sub
```

Please give me any hints you might have to help me solve this.

Comment: Silverlight relies on the http caching mechanisms to determine the necessity of updates. The next thing to try is watching the update request in fiddler. The response will most likely be an unmodified one and not contain a xap (hence no "UpdateAvailable"). You can then repeat the request manually in fiddler and figure out why the response is deemed unnecessary.

Comment: I don't know what fiddler is.

Comment: It's an extremely popular tool to analyze web requests. You'll need it every time you want to learn what is really going on at the http layer. I'm pretty sure you are in such a situation. The tool itself is easy to use but you will need a bit of knowledge about http caching headers to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer that worked for me in one of the other forums. I am posting it here in case someone else has this problem:

I added these lines to my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig.

```
<object>
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true"/>
  </object>
```

The hint also said to sign the xap which I did but the problem didn't go away until I modified the ClientConfig.

Bob